# Search points to /search/?s=KEYWORD instead of /search/KEYWORD

Tags: permalinks, search

I can access my search page and results correctly here /search/KEYWORD but when I click search it points to /search/?s=KEYWORD.

I updated my permalinks in the admin.

Comment: What theme do you use? What does the `<form action="` in the `search.php` file (if present) say? Do you have any redirects - either in your `functions.php` (or any other PHP file) or in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: form action used is /search because I created a page for this one. I only have redirects that WP created.